# Joda Years.yearsBetween issue?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, gregorian-calendar

I have 2 DateTime values: `date1 = "1492-10-12"` and `date2 = "1992-10-12"`.
When I use `Years.yearsBetween(date1, date2).getYears()`, I get **499**.  I was expecting **500**.
If I use `date1 = "1892-10-12"` and `date2 = "1992-10-12`", then I get `100`.

In diagnosing the issue, I found that the problem first occurs when I have 2 DateTime values: `date1 = "1492-10-12"` and `date2 = "1583-10-12"`.  I get **90** years when I should be getting **91**.  When `date2 = "1582-10-12"` or earlier, then the calculation is correct.

I am assuming that this is because the Gregorian calendar started in **1582**, but I'm not sure why we are 1 year off.  Any ideas?  Is **499** theoretically correct or is there a problem with with yearsBetween when **1582** falls within the start and end dates?

My code looks like:

```
Date date1 = null;
Date date2 = null;
try {
    date1 = sdf.parse("1492-10-12");
    date2 = sdf.parse("1992-10-12");
} 
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int yrs = computeDiffInYears(date1, date2);  ?? yrs = 499

private static int computeDiffInYears(Date date1, Date date2) {
    DateTime dt1 = (new DateTime(date1));
    DateTime dt2 = (new DateTime(date2));
    return Years.yearsBetween(dt1, dt2).getYears();
}
```

**UPDATE:** If I rewrite the method, computeDiffInYears, as suggested by Anarki as:

```
private static int computeDiffInYears(Date date1, Date date2) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(sdf.format(date1));
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(sdf.format(date2));
    return Years.yearsBetween(dt1, dt2).getYears();
}
```

then it works correctly

Comment: My mistake - it was introduced by Pope Gregory in 1582 and adopted in England in 1752.  So is this just a coincidence that the problem starts around 1582?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Adoption): "the new calendar was implemented on the date specified by the bull, with Julian Thursday, 4 October 1582, being followed by Gregorian Friday, 15 October 1582".

Comment: Why the down votes?  I have done the research and did not find this issue previously addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date first = sdf.parse("12-10-1492");
    Date last = sdf.parse("12-10-1992");
    System.out.println(getDiffYears(first, last));
}

public static int getDiffYears(Date first, Date last) {
    Calendar a = getCalendar(first);
    Calendar b = getCalendar(last);
    int diff = b.get(Calendar.YEAR) - a.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (a.get(Calendar.MONTH) > b.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            || (a.get(Calendar.MONTH) == b.get(Calendar.MONTH) && a.get(Calendar.DATE) > b.get(Calendar.DATE))) {
        diff--;
    }
    return diff;
}

public static Calendar getCalendar(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

It print 500 witch is correct.

**Edit**

I just tried this (using Joda) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime("1492-10-12");
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime("1992-10-12");
    int yrs = computeDiffInYears(date1, date2);
    System.out.println(yrs);
}

private static int computeDiffInYears(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
    return Years.yearsBetween(date1, date2).getYears();
}
```

It also print 500, but when i try to make a conversion from Date to DateTime it print 499, so you should use only DateTime or Calendar.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.  I would prefer to use Joda.  Still wondering if this is a bug.

Comment: I just try this Years diff = Years.yearsBetween(new DateTime("1492-10-12"), new DateTime("1992-10-12"));
diff.getYears() print 500 !

Comment: This is very strange.  I have a Date object for date1 and date2, when I get the invalid 499.  If I convert my date objects to Strings, then it works as you suggest.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Anarki.  You have solved my problem although I think there is a problem when using date objects vs. Strings when instantiating DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Joda does not include the actual "to" date but the day before. in that case the calculation is correct.

Comment: `If I use date1 = "1892-10-12" and date2 = "1992-10-12", then I get 100.` ... shouldn't he get `99` instead?